# Reverse every K-element Sub-List

Tags: python, reverse, singly-linked-list, sublist

I am having trouble concatenating my previous list with my current reversed list. The question is as follows...

Given the head of a LinkedList and a number ‘k’, reverse every ‘k’ sized sub-list starting from the head. If, in the end, you are left with a sub-list with less than ‘k’ elements, reverse it too.

I just thought I'd keep a `counter` that always gets updated to reverse a max of k sized sub_list starting from the `head` of the list. Find where that `end` should be and have a `start` pointing to the start of the list.

In order to reverse any list of any size less than or equal to k I just check if `end is None`.

The `start` of the list becomes the end of the list and because `end` actually points to `k + 1` node, the first iteration concatenates the first reversal of k nodes with the rest of the list by `start.next = end`, where `start` point to the last node of the reversed list and `end` points to the start of the other list.

I know my problem lies when during the second iteration when the list reverses I am losing reference my list from before (we can think of this as the first half). For example, for my first iteration the list

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8, k = 3
```

becomes,

```
3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8
```

but after the second iteration I no longer have `sub_list` with the first 3 nodes

```
from __future__ import print_function


class Node:
  def __init__(self, value, next=None):
    self.value = value
    self.next = next

  def print_list(self):
    temp = self
    while temp is not None:
      print(temp.value, end=" ")
      temp = temp.next
    print()


def reverse_every_k_elements(head, k):
  start, end = head, head
  previous = None

  while end is not None:
    counter = k

    while end is not None and counter > 0:
      end = end.next
      counter -= 1
    
    sub_list = reverse(start, end)
    start.next = end
    start = end
    
    if previous:
      previous.next = end
    else:
      previous = end

  


def reverse(head, stop_node):
  previous = None

  while head is not stop_node:
    _next = head.next
    head.next = previous
    previous = head
    head = _next

  return previous


def main():
  head = Node(1)
  head.next = Node(2)
  head.next.next = Node(3)
  head.next.next.next = Node(4)
  head.next.next.next.next = Node(5)
  head.next.next.next.next.next = Node(6)
  head.next.next.next.next.next.next = Node(7)
  head.next.next.next.next.next.next.next = Node(8)

  print("Nodes of original LinkedList are: ", end='')
  head.print_list()
  result = reverse_every_k_elements(head, 3)
  print("Nodes of reversed LinkedList are: ", end='')
  result.print_list()


main()
```

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `end` is the node *after* the reversed section, or -- otherwise put -- the first node of the rest of the list which is still to be processed, you should not have:

```
previous.next = end
```

The section that was reversed has now as its first node the one referenced by `sub_list`, so:

```
previous.next = sub_list
```

This is the only `next` link that needs updating besides the reversals, so no need for this update:

```
start.next = end
```

When `previous` was `None`, then instead of `previous.next` we should set `head`:

```
head = sub_list
```

These are the most important changes to do. With some other adaptations we get this:

```
def reverse_every_k_elements(head, k):
  start, end = None, head

  while end is not None:
    previous = start 
    start = end

    counter = k
    while end is not None and counter > 0:
      end = end.next
      counter -= 1
    
    sub_list = reverse(start, end)
    
    # Here the magic (of linking the pieces) happens:
    if previous:
      previous.next = sub_list
    else:
      head = sub_list

  # Need to return the head...
  return head
```